# Getting setState is not a function

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am getting the following error

> //bundle.js:31367 Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a
>   function//

**JSX:**

```
  componentDidMount(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://intelligencevillage.wxtui.cn/index.php/Api/HomepageWebview/getHomepageData/area_id/5',
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
    }).done(function({data}){
        this.setState({
            lis1:[data.banner]
        })
    })
}
```

I understand that its some sort of binding issue, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: function({data}) {...}.bind(this)

Comment: "Where to add .bind(this) in this demo to make it work" --- just try adding it here and there, after few attempts you finally will be lucky!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with Function Execution Scope.

```
componentDidMount(){
    $.ajax({
      ...
    }).done(function({data}){
        ///// HERE {this}
        // try console.log(this);
        // you will see there is no`setState`
        this.setState({
            lis1:[data.banner]
        })
    })
}
```

Now, function inside the `done` chain, `this` reference only inside the function.

### Easy Fix:Use Fat Arror Function

```
componentDidMount(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'',
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
    }).done(({data}) => {
        this.setState({
            lis1:[data.banner]
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in your case doesn't represent the correct context. Function inside `.done()` represents a separate context for itself and thus either you can

**1**.  Add `bind(this)` after the `.done()`.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

        lis1:[],

    }

}
componentDidMount(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'',
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
    }).done(function({data}){
        this.setState({
            lis1:[data.banner]
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

**2**  Or you can assign `this` to a separate variable and use that.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

        lis1:[],

    }

}
componentDidMount(){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:'',
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
    }).done(function({data}){
        self.setState({
            lis1:[data.banner]
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Give it another try.

Comment: ".done() creates a separate context" --- nope. "add bind(this) after the .done()" --- nope.

Comment: `.bind(this)` for `this.setState` is still wrong. Guess further